# Programmatically Get the Magento Product URL Suffix?

Tags: magento

Is there any way to get the Product URL Suffix in Magento settings to be used in the templates where I want to use it? I found this doc page: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product.html

And found this method: **getProductUrlSuffix**

But I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation, this function will give you the product rewrite suffix. It takes an optional parameter, which is the store ID.

The class the link points to is a helper, meaning you can access it in the template files.

First get the helper, then call the function.

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product');
$suffix = $helper->getProductUrlSuffix(); // may have particular store ID
```